# C# Timer throwing an error during loop?

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, timer, error-handling

This code right here shows a "type writer effect" I have used to print out a text output to the user. Basically it prints out text with a type writer effect. But it throws an error:

> **“Index and length must refer to a location within the string”**

Here's my code:

```
private void TypeWriterTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int MaxRetries = 5;

            for (int i = 0; i < MaxRetries; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Action final = () => dialogBox.Text = typeWriterReply.Substring(0, TypeWriter_index_Num) + "_";//Substring is a part of Type_Text String that we declared at the start
                    dialogBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(final, null);

                    TypeWriter_index_Num++;//Doing a post fix
                    if (TypeWriter_index_Num == typeWriterReply.Length +1)//An if statment with a condition of course
                    {
                        TypeWriter_index_Num = 0;
                        TypeWriterTimer.Stop();
                    }
                    dialogBox.Focus();
                    dialogBox.CaretIndex = dialogBox.Text.Length;
                    dialogBox.ScrollToEnd();

                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception tw)
                {
                    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Type Writer ERROR");
                    Console.WriteLine(tw.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

TypeWriterReply is the text that is being printed and all of the variables are declared globally.

Why does it throw this error?

Comment: The expression "TypeWriter_index_Num == typeWriterReply.Length +1" is certainly a bug, if not the one you are asking about. The only valid indexes into the string are values _less than_ typeWriterReply.Length. You're stopping one character too late.

Comment: Please don't code like this: `catch (Exception tw)`. It is a bad practice to catch all exceptions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much shorter, simpler, beautiful way of doing it, using C#'s [async / await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) awesomeness:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.TypeWriter"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TypeWriter" Height="300" Width="300">
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox"/>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class TypeWriter : Window
{
    public TypeWriter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TypeText();
    }

    public async void TypeText()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        var text = "Hello, World! I'm simulating typing into this TextBox.";

        foreach (var character in text)
        {
            this.TextBox.Text += character;

            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you But if I run the method for the second time, it appends the text before. How do I clean the textbox first and run this code? Plus, is there a way to add a _ at the end of the printing process that it produces this effect: "Hello world_" :)

Comment: @ProgrammingFreak just add `this.TextBox.Text = string.Empty;` before the `foreach` loop... looks obvious, doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you! Tried that but it kinda scrambled my words sometimes, Second loop caused it to print the words as "Holel wrlod!" and stuff like that. A good solution over timers tho

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty typewriter effect, currently I am looping through the text but you could just stop the timer instead.

[image]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private int _length;
        private string _text;

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            _text = "Hello, world !";
            var timer = new Timer(100);
            timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
            _length++;
            if (_length > _text.Length) _length = 0;
            var substring = _text.Substring(0, _length);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => { TextBlock1.Text = substring; }));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** here a version that stops at the end instead

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    _length++;
    if (_length > _text.Length) {
        Timer timer = (Timer)sender;
        timer.Stop();
        return;
    }
    var substring = _text.Substring(0, _length);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => { TextBlock1.Text = substring; }));
}
```